# How to connect command with resulting events

Tags: architecture, event-handling, cqrs, event-driven

I try to modularize our extensive legacy system. I think of using Command/Query/Events as the public API of each module and focusing on communication. I want to model whole communication in async fashion. But to effectively use Command/Event, I need to know that a particular event has been raised as an effect of a particular command. For example, I want to dispatch a command Book(SKU, quantity) to the Warehouse module. Then I am interested in the result of that concrete command, not in any event regarding booking items in the warehouse. Some sides may dispatch identical (semantically) commands simultaneously, but I am interested (as a client module) in a result of my command only. I know I may attach correlationID to my events but AFAIK it is more about tracking/debuging and not about application design itself. What are the alternatives here?

The problem also relates to sagas. Let's say there is the Set aggregate. It allows you to add numbers inside. Set is allowed to accept the same number multiple times. Saga emits command Add(setId, number) and waits for event Added(setId, number). How do we know if that event arose due to our command? Someone else might, in the meantime, dispatch the same command. But we want to be sure it is the event that resulted from our command. It is not important that a particular number has been added to the set. What is important is that our number has been added (even if duplicated). Maybe there is a mental flaw in my thinking. Maybe the system should care about real consequences? But it is hard to imagine how I might resolve the issue above.

Comment: Your event would be something like `MyCommandCompletedEvent`. It should definitely contain the id of the original command and that's how your client will correlate the event with the command.

Answer (score 1):

If the domain cares about which command gave rise to an event (whether in a saga or not), there's nothing wrong with including something sufficient to identify the command (could be a unique ID provided by the requestor, could be the entire command with some metadata, whatever) in the event.

That said, there's something to be said for commands which have the interpretation: "make the state of the system conform to this request".  In these cases, you don't care that a particular command changed the state, because caring about that (especially when retries are introduced) requires you to record a dummy event which doesn't actually change the state when you have a command (e.g. a retry, but it can also arise normally because the requestor might be operating off of a stale view).

If you care that a particular command is accepted, it's probably overall a better course to give those commands request/response semantics and respond with a success message.

- process 1 sends `Add(set123, 4)`
- `Added(set123, 4)` is persisted
- success response is not received by process 1
- process 2 (or perhaps a retry of process 1, it doesn't really matter) sends `Add(set123, 4)`
- since 4 is already in `set123`, a success response is sent

Comment: I've heard about the idea of keeping read/query/log about each command status or even publishing kind of application event CommandSucceed(commandId). That is probably not what you mean here. I want to keep that communication async, and I do not wish to interfere with my domain by differentiating commands types. How may I approach that request/reply async pattern here? I assume my request is still the command, but the reply is no longer an event. But how are those pieces connected then?

Comment: Publishing a `CommandSucceeded(commandId)` event is perfectly acceptable. If you have a requirement that it be known which command succeeded and you're not making assumptions beyond "there's a stream of domain events" around how the domain layer interacts with other layers, then that implies that some means of differentiating commands (not necessarily their types) _is_ an intrinsic part of your domain and that publishing which commands have succeeded is the only way you can do it.

Comment: It may help to remember Klang's Conjecture: If you can't map out how you would solve this using only people, pens, and paper, you have no reasonable expectation of how you would solve it with software/computers.

Comment: I consider a command hander as part of application layer, not the domain layer. As far as all domain events getting raised from aggregates, publishing additional application events from the command handler would be feasible. There might even be some dedicated bus for such messages (command succeed, command failed). Is such reasoning reasonable? To handle retrying, I probably have to keep a log of commands anyway, am I? Where may I read more about all that stuff?